# I was making a program in java that prints numbers from 1 to x (x being the user input value). This is using a for loop and a method statement

Tags: java

This is using a for loop and a method statement.

```
   `import java.util.Scanner;
    class MethodLoop{
        public static void main(String [] args){
            Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            int x= s.nextInt();
        }
        public static void print (int y){
            for(int y=1;y<x;x++){
                System.out.println(y);
            }
        }
    }`
```

//public static void print is where I get my errors

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity. For example: consider using a shorter, more concise title, explaining the context for your code snippet, and listing the errors you're receiving.

Comment: The numbers between 1 and x aren't printing. There is no error being shown. All it asks is for the number and that is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your program.You are trying to use variable `x` but it is not visible in the scope of function `print(int)` since it is neither global nor it is passed as parameter.

Next, you are probably meaning to pass `x` as a parameter to the `print` function, instead of `y`, so that you can use it as a limit in the loop.

Finally you are declaring `y` as loop variable, but you are increasing `x`. This code can easily finish in an infinite loop. You probably want to increase `y`. And now you are ready to call the function from `main`.

Here is a (possible) solution that you may have thought of:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MethodLoop{
public static void main(String [] args){
     Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
     int x= s.nextInt();
     print(x);
 }
 public static void print (int x){
     for(int y=1;y<x;y++){
         System.out.println(y);
     }
 }}
```

Comment: Is your code inside a class?  Do you have a line like `public class myProgram{` above the code you've supplied?

Comment: on top there should be `import java.util.Scanner;`

Comment: @BobetJohn This was supposed to be just a snippet but ok, I added also the import. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @NiVeR no problem

Answer (score 1):

change `public static void print (int y){` to `public static void print (int x){` and then call it from main.

*edit*
yes also change loop to be `y++`

Comment: It is not printing the numbers between 1 and x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to pass **x**, instead of y in your print method.
Also, you should increment **y**, instead of x in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a local variable from another block. You can try adding x as parameter and call print method from main method.

Answer (score 1):

As Logan said in a comment, your problem is that the `print` method doesn't "know about" the `x` variable.  What you need to do is hand that method the variable in the arguments - the things in the brackets.  So change it to `public static void print (int x)`  That moves hands the `x` variable to your method.  Then, you're incrementing (increasing) x in the `for` loop, you need to increment `y` instead by changing `x++` to `y++`

Finally, you need to actually tell your program to use that method by putting `print(x)` at the bottom of your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the for loop in print() method with condition  `y <= x`,
also update the variable name passed in `public static void print(int x)`
and after taking user input call `print(x)`